# "multiple definition of..." error for a full specialisation of a template function

Tags: c++, templates, definition

I have a project with configuration:

```
./main.cpp  
./type_traints/TypeTraints.cpp
./type_traints/TypeTraints.hpp
./type_traints/chapter_20.hpp
```

The ./type_traints/CMakeLists.txt file is:

```
 cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.8)
 add_library(chapter_20 TypeTraints.cpp)
```

and the ./CMakeLists.txt follows:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.8)
project (mpl)

add_subdirectory(type_traints)
include_directories(type_traints)
link_directories(type_traints)

add_executable (mpl main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(mpl chapter_20)
```

Relevant parts of files (most includes omitted) include:
./type_traints/chapter_20.hpp

```
#ifndef CHAPTER_20_GUARD
#define CHAPTER_20_GUARD
#include <TypeTraints.hpp>

void chapter_20() {
  test_23();
}   
#endif //CHAPTER_20_GUARD
```

./type_traints/TypeTraints.hpp

```
#ifndef TYPE_TRAINTS_GUARD
#define TYPE_TRAINTS_GUARD
namespace details {

  template<class T> const char* class2name() {
    return "unknown";
  };

  template<> const char* class2name<int>() {
    return "int";
  };
}

template<class T>
class type_descriptor {
  friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& stream, 
                                    const type_descriptor<T>& desc) {
    stream << desc.getName();
    return stream;
  }

public:
  std::string getName() const;  
};

template<class T>
std::string type_descriptor<T>::getName() const {
  return details::class2name<T>();
}

void test_23();    
#endif // TYPE_TRAINTS_GUARD
```

./type_traints/TypeTraints.cpp

```
#include<TypeTraints.hpp>

void test_23() {
  cout << type_descriptor<int>() << endl;
}
```

and ./main.cpp

```
#include <chapter_20.hpp>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
chapter_20();
  return 0;
}
```

The project compiles but fails to link:

```
[ 50%] Building CXX object type_traints/CMakeFiles/chapter_20.dir/TypeTraints.cpp.o
Linking CXX static library libchapter_20.a
[ 50%] Built target chapter_20
[100%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/mpl.dir/main.cpp.o
Linking CXX executable mpl
type_traints/libchapter_20.a(TypeTraints.cpp.o): In function `char const* details::cl
ass2name<int>()':                                                                   
/home/marcin/Projects/mpl/type_traints/TypeTraints.hpp:312: multiple definition of `c
har const* details::class2name<int>()'                                              
CMakeFiles/mpl.dir/main.cpp.o:/home/marcin/Projects/mpl/type_traints/TypeTraints.hpp:
312: first defined here                                                             
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [mpl] Błąd 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/mpl.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
23:56:20@marcin-laptop ~/P
```

The project links fine if I remove the class2name specialization (`class2name<int>()`) from TypeTraints.hpp and use only the generic implementation.

Does anybody have an idea Why is that? Did I miss-configure cmake files?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In short: an explicitly (i.e. fully) specialized template function *is no longer a template*. It is an ordinary function and it obeys One Definition Rule for ordinary functions.

In other words you can't define explicitly specialized function templates in header file. Doing so will result in ODR violations.

A template is a template only as long as it depends on at least one parameter. I.e. *partial* specializations can be *defined* in header files (since they are still *templates*). *Explicit* (i.e. full) specializations can only be *declared* in header files, but have to be *defined* in implementation files, just like ordinary functions.

Comment: Thank you for answering. However, changing function definition to declaration (template<> const char* class2name<int>();) in TypeTraints.hpp and adding a definition in TypeTraints.cpp (template<> const char* class2name<int>() {return "int"} yields a compilatin error: "/home/marcin/Projects/mpl/type_traints/TypeTraints.cpp:120: error: expected initializer before ‘<’ token"

Comment: @Marcin: You screwed something up. No way to tell without seeing the new code. I'd guess that you forgot about the namespace. The definition should either be done inside `details` namespace, or a qualified name should be used (i.e. it has to explicitly state that it is `details::class2name<int>` you are defining).

Comment: Yep, I've screwed the namespace. A tried programmer is a dumb programmer :/ Thank you you're great!

Answer (score 3):

This is a violation of the one definition rule :

> There can be more than one definition
>   of a class type (clause 9),
>   enumeration type (7.2), inline
>   function with external linkage
>   (7.1.2), class template (clause 14),
>   non-static function template (14.5.5),
>   static data member of a class template
>   (14.5.1.3), member function of a class
>   template (14.5.1.1), or **template
>   specialization for which some template
>   parameters are not specified** (14.7,
>   14.5.4) in a program provided that each definition appears in a different
>   translation unit, and provided the
>   definitions satisfy the following
>   requirements.

An explicit specialization of the `class2name` template function does not fall in any of these cases. For this reason, I believe that moving `class2name<int>()` definition into an implementation file should fix the issue. I also think you should have a look on ["Why not specialize function templates ?"](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm).

Comment: I'am aware of the drawbacks of template function specialization - this is just an educational exercise

Answer (score 1):

Your files:

```
./main.cpp  
./type_traints/TypeTraints.cpp  
./type_traints/TypeTraints.hpp  
./type_traints/chapter_20.hpp
```

in which TypeTraints.hpp is directly included in TypeTraits.cpp and indirectly included in main.cpp(through chapter_20.hpp). However, you fully specification template

```
 template<> const char* class2name<int>() {
     return "int";
 };
```

is defined in TypeTraints.hpp which be existing in two different compilation units(the above two .cpp file). These two files will be linked together after compilation and this cause the multiple definition link error.

Comment: Just wondering, why doesn't the include guard protect against multiple definitions in this case?